# Confusing Code, request help

Tags: bash, programming

I need help. I am recently coding a bash script, which I have 26 sets of variables. I'm stuck on this part which I need help with. I noticed when you install Ubuntu to check out this website if you need help, and now I do. Basically, I have variables labeled l#a, with number being any number 1-26. What I want to do is this:
it loops a range just like how you count from 1 to 10, there's only 9 digits. But, in this, i want it to count it as if there were 64. Let's put it like this.

Starting from "l1a", it starts at 0, and keeps adding 1 until it gets to 64, when it gets to 64, it waits until the moment it can tick to 65, but instead of going that far, it checks the successor's (in this case "l2a") value, and if it is not 64, it ticks it by 1, and sets l1a to 0, If it is, it checks the next one to see if it's 64 or not, if not, it ticks that by 1 and sets everything before that to 0, if it is, it checks the next, and so on. When it finds one that isn't 64, it ticks it, and every predecessor's value gets changed back to 0. But, if it goes all the way to l26a, and it's 64, as well as all the other digits, it ends the code.

THE CODE:

```
l1a=0
l2a=0
l3a=0
l4a=0
l5a=0
l6a=0
l7a=0
l8a=0
l9a=0
l10a=0
l11a=0
l12a=0
l13a=0
l14a=0
l15a=0
l16a=0
l17a=0
l18a=0
l19a=0
l20a=0
l21a=0
l22a=0
l23a=0
l24a=0
l25a=0
l26a=0
l1b="0"
l2b="0"
l3b="0"
l4b="0"
l5b="0"
l6b="0"
l7b="0"
l8b="0"
l9b="0"
l10b="0"
l11b="0"
l12b="0"
l13b="0"
l14b="0"
l15b="0"
l16b="0"
l17b="0"
l18b="0"
l19b="0"
l20b="0"
l21b="0"
l22b="0"
l23b="0"
l24b="0"
l25b="0"
l26b="0"
n=1
n2=0
p=1
let n2 = n + 1
l=0
u10="_"
u11="a"
u12="b"
u13="c"
u14="d"
u15="e"
u16="f"
u17="g"
u18="h"
u19="i"
u20="j"
u21="k"
u22="l"
u23="m"
u24="n"
u25="o"
u26="p"
u27="q"
u28="r"
u29="s"
u30="t"
u31="u"
u32="v"
u33="w"
u34="x"
u35="y"
u36="z"
u37="A"
u38="B"
u39="C"
u40="D"
u41="E"
u42="F"
u43="G"
u44="H"
u45="G"
u46="H"
u47="I"
u48="J"
u49="K"
u50="L"
u51="M"
u52="N"
u53="O"
u54="P"
u55="Q"
u56="R"
u57="S"
u58="T"
u59="U"
u60="V"
u61="W"
u62="X"
u63="Y"
u64="Z"
while true; do
    cd /home/eddy/Pictures/MCSkins/Auto
let n = 1
if [ "$l" -lt "10" ]; then
    let l"$n"b = l"$n"a
else
    let l"$n"b = u"$l"
fi
if [ "$l" -le "64" ]; then
    let l = l + 1
else
    if [ "$l+$p" -le "64" ]; then
        let
```

Comment: Please add the part of the code where we can see the loop.

Comment: It's incomplete, but I'll post it.

Comment: There, but it looks funny in the format :P

Answer (score 2):

Ouch! This perfect for arrays:

```
declare -a la lb
for n in {1..26}; do
    la[$n]=0
    lb[$n]="0"
done

declare -a u=(
    [10]="_" [11]="a" [12]="b" [13]="c" [14]="d" [15]="e" [16]="f" [17]="g"
    [18]="h" [19]="i" [20]="j" [21]="k" [22]="l" [23]="m" [24]="n" [25]="o"
    [26]="p" [27]="q" [28]="r" [29]="s" [30]="t" [31]="u" [32]="v" [33]="w"
    [34]="x" [35]="y" [36]="z" [37]="A" [38]="B" [39]="C" [40]="D" [41]="E"
    [42]="F" [43]="G" [44]="H" [45]="G" [46]="H" [47]="I" [48]="J" [49]="K"
    [50]="L" [51]="M" [52]="N" [53]="O" [54]="P" [55]="Q" [56]="R" [57]="S"
    [58]="T" [59]="U" [60]="V" [61]="W" [62]="X" [63]="Y" [64]="Z"
)

declare -i n
declare -i n2
declare -i l
declare -i p=1

cd /home/eddy/Pictures/MCSkins/Auto
while true; do
n=1
if (( $l < 10 )); then
    lb[$n]=${la[$n]}
else
    lb[$n]=${u[$l]}
fi
if (( $l <= 64 )); then
    ((l++))
else
    if (( $l + $p <= 64 )); then
        # ...
```